# How to Organize Table Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

i need to organize time attendance table from this

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| userId | CheckTime | CheckType |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      | 09:10     | In        |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      | 16:02     | In        |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      | 19:50     | Out       |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

to this

```
+--------+---------+----------+
| userId | CheckIn | CheckOut |
+--------+---------+----------+
| 1      | 09:10   |          |
+        +---------+----------+
|        | 16:02   | 19:50    |
+        +---------+----------+
|        |         |          |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

in Razor Engine I  tried the following

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            @foreach (var usergroup in Model.Usersquery.GroupBy(g => g.UserId))
            {

                foreach (var checkin in Model.Attendancequery.Where(a => a.UserId == usergroup.Key && a.CheckType == "In"))
                {
                    var checkout = @Model.Attendancequery.Where(a => a.UserId == usergroup.Key && a.CheckType == "Out" && a.CheckTime > checkin.CheckTime).Select(d => (DateTime?)d.CheckTime).DefaultIfEmpty().FirstOrDefault();
                    var hours = checkout - checkin.CheckTime;
            <tr>
                <th>@usergroup.FirstOrDefault(f => f.UserId == usergroup.Key).Name</th>
                <td>@checkin.CheckTime.ToShortTimeString()</td>
                @if (checkout.HasValue)
                {
                    var cc = (DateTime)checkout;
                <td>@cc.ToShortTimeString()</td>
                } else{<td>@checkout</td>}
                <td>@hours</td>
            </tr>
                }

            }
        </table>
```

the problem is, its counting the same checkout for every check in.
I would be glad for any help...

Comment: Add `Date Column` to the table and match your expressions with Date.

Comment: it's matched with date from the controller. those are on the same date

Comment: It's Better to keep them in the Controller. but, you need to sort each user's records by `CheckTime` column. in this way you can recognize that which checkout is for which CheckIn. I would like to do them in more clearer in code behinds.